# Java based SSL CLIENT walk-through, that covers pulling a JSON object from a Restful service

Tags: java, rest, ssl, truststore, walkthrough

A 30 second search and I've hundreds of examples of how to do this via: Curl, Perl, Python, PhP, ... but nothing for Java. There's just a lot of noise from bodies having problems getting any of the numerous SSL implementations to work.

So wondering is there a from scratch walkthrough that covers the Maven tweaks (or at least the imports) needed to get a working set of dependencies, and enough detail to cover the basics (working code sample) to uses the bundled Java Truststore to say pull one JSON object, over a properly signed connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient API and call a HTTPS URL which returns a JSON object. Please check - [HttpClient - SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html)

Comment: Thanks but that's not a walkthrough, just a code snippet, for 5% of the task. A walkthrough would start with open Eclipse and click File->New